# Display records in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I need to display  all case records which are present in organization in a table format by using visualforce page

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to Salesforce Trailhead and the [Visualforce Basics](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/visualforce_fundamentals) module. The chapter '[Displaying Records, Fields and Tables](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_output_components)' will show you how to achieve this.

> Display A Table
>
> Use  to add a table of data to a page. What
>   exactly is a related list? What does  do when you
>   add it to a page? It grabs a list of similar data elements. For
>   example, a list of contacts for the account. It sets up a table with
>   columns for each field, headers atop each column, and so on. For each
>   item in the list—for each related contact—it adds a row to the table,
>   and fills in each column with the appropriate field from that record.
>   You can do the same thing in your own Visualforce markup using
>   iteration components. An iteration component works with a collection
>   of similar items, instead of on a single value. For example,
>   {!Account.contacts} is an expression that evaluates to a list of
>   contacts for an account. You can use this expression with an iteration
>   component to create a list or table with details of these related
>   contacts.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.contacts}" var="contact">
      <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!contact.Title}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

> A table listing the account’s contacts is added to the page, with just
>   the columns you’ve chosen.

The key Visualforce attribute here is **apex:pageBlockTable**. This tag generates the markup for a list view or related list table in the Force.com GUI. It is bound to a collection of objects and each row rendered is an item in that collection.

Answer (score -1):

1. Use below blog for custom pagination. Instead of Account object use Case object.

http://www.redpointcrm.com/add-pagination-to-your-visualforce-pages-using-the-soql-offset-clause

2. Pagination with a List Controller

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_pagination.htm